# DAX How do I calculate Exchange Rate between two tables?

Tags: dax

I have a table **Sales** with fields: **Date**, **Revenue**, and **CurrencyCode**

I have a table **ExchangeRate** with fields **ValidFrom**, **ValidTo**, **ExchangeRate**, and **CurrencyCode**.

I need to multiply **revenue** by the **ExchangeRate**, when the sales **Date** falls between **ValidFrom** and **ValidTo** and the **CurrencyCode** from both tables match.

Comment: Does your model have a relationship between ExchangeRate and Sales using CurrencyCode column?

Comment: No, but I can create a bridge table with unique CurrencyCodes.

Comment: I think it is not strictly necessary but should make things easier, try my answer though it could work for you without adding any relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a calculate column in the `Sales` table to take the `Rate` from `ExchangeRate` table then just multiply `Rate` by the `Revenue` value in an additional column or a measure.

Use this expression in the `Sales` calculated column, I named `ExchangeRate`

```
ExchangeRate =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( ExchangeRate[ExchangeRate] ),
    FILTER (
        FILTER ( ExchangeRate, [CurrencyCode] = EARLIER ( Sales[CurrencyCode] ) ),
        [ValidFrom] <= EARLIER ( Sales[Date] )
            && [ValidTo] >= EARLIER ( Sales[Date] )
    )
)
```

Now you can create a measure for multiplying the Rate by the Revenune:

```
RevenueXRateMeasure = SUM(Sales[Revenue])*SUM(Sales[ExchangeRate])
```

Or if you prefer a column use:

```
RevenueXRateColumn = [Revenue]*[ExchangeRate]
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: The EARLIER function was totally new to me. Also, what is the purpose of having nested FILTERs?

Comment: @ronrule, The EARLIER function lets us access columns in Sales table from a ExchangeRate table context. The inner FILTER is leaving only the rows which CurrencyCode is the same than the CurrencyCode in the Sales table, the second FILTER takes that rows and filters those rows that fall in the date range.